# Inserting events to calendar using intents. Error in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, calendar

I am working on Android 4.4.2(API 19). I am using the below code to insert an event into my calendar

```
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2014, 5, 29, 7, 30);
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2014, 5, 29, 8, 30);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
            .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
            .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
            .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com");
    startActivity(intent);
```

I have a button in the home screen of my app. On click of the button, the above code gets invoked. When I try this on my emulator , I get the following error,

"NO Calendars  Before you can add an event , you must add at least one calendar account to your device"
I also tried creating a new avd deleting the previous avd, but still stuck with the same error.Please help.

Comment: Did you try adding a Calendar on the device through the Google Calendar app?

Comment: @JDJ There is already a Calendar App installed in the emulator. I created an AVD with the following specifications:Target : Android 4.4.2(API level 19) Skin: HVGA SD Card : 2G Snapshot True hw.device.name:Nexus 7 2013 hw.accelerometer yes

Comment: Also in the AVD , I checked under Settings -> Accounts -> IMAP. It shows the accounts I had added and which are also Synced. Please advice what might be a solution to this.

Comment: In the AVD, are you using an existing Calendar account or a new one?

Comment: @JDJ I am using my existing calendar account (my gmail account).Also, when I try to install the Google API using SDK manager, it prompts me with the following error message " cmd.exe and java.exe" are blocking sdk/tools directory. I believe I should install Google API so that I can create an AVD with target as Google API API level 19.